# Capture all futures in a Zone

Tags: dart, dart-async

In Dart is there any way to capture all `Future`'s created inside a [Zone](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.2/dart-async/Zone-class.html)?

Currently, I'm forced to manually capture them all, but this seems prone to forgetting to do it. So I want to automate this if possible.

In the example code below I want to capture `someAsyncWork` so I can await it after the main `runPluginCode` has run.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> main() async {
  print('Run plugin code');
  await runZoned(
    () async {
      runPluginCode();

      final tasks = Zone.current['tasks'] as List<Future>;

      await Future.wait(tasks);
    },
    zoneValues: {
      'taskId': 123,
      'tasks': <Future>[],
    },
  );
  print('Exit plugin code');
}

void runPluginCode() {
  // External QuickJS script that only has sync API methods
  // but they may call into async functions that need to be awaited before
  // the plugin code ends
  someTask();
}

void someTask() {
  print('performing task');
  // I don't want manually do this everywhere
  // final tasks = Zone.current['tasks'] as List<Future>;
  // tasks.add(someAsyncWork());
  someAsyncWork();
}

Future<void> someAsyncWork() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
  final taskId = Zone.current['taskId'] as int;
  print('async work completed for task $taskId did I complete inside the plugin code???');
}
```

I believe this should be possible when using a custom [ZoneSpecification](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.2/dart-async/ZoneSpecification-class.html)

I tried this but without any luck.

```dart
    zoneSpecification: ZoneSpecification(
      run: <R>(self, parent, zone, f) {
        final task = parent.run(zone, f);
        if (task is Future) {
          (zone['tasks'] as List<Future>).add(task);
        }
        return task;
      },
      runUnary: <R, T>(self, parent, zone, f, arg) {
        final task = parent.runUnary(zone, f, arg);
        if (task is Future) {
          (zone['tasks'] as List<Future>).add(task);
        }
        return task;
      },
      runBinary: <R, T1, T2>(self, parent, zone, f, arg1, arg2) {
        final task = parent.runBinary(zone, f, arg1, arg2);
        if (task is Future) {
          (zone['tasks'] as List<Future>).add(task);
        }
        return task;
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no way to capture all futures, or any futures, created inside a Zone.

Zones are a lower-level abstraction than futures. Futures are built on top of zones, so zones do not know anything about futures, or streams.

You can respond to anyone calling `then` on the future, because that calls `zone.registerUnaryCallback`, but just creating the future is a simple operation that doesn't do any zone-related operations. It captures the current zone (which it really shouldn't need to do), but that is it.

If you want to make sure that all computation inside the zone has completed, then ... well, you probably cannot, but you can get closer by:

- noticing every `Zone.createTimer`, `Zone.createPeriodicTimer` and `Zone.scheduleMicrotask`. Then you can know whether there are any of those pending. (Which you'd need to know to know that the zone is "done", not just whether there are uncompleted futures.)
- noticing every `registerCallback` (and `..Unary..` and `..Binary..`), to know that there is *some* code which expects to (maybe) get called in that zone. The problem is that not all of those will be run, for example, a `future.then(handleValue, onError: handleError)` will only call one of `handleValue` and `handleError`, but it registers both. Then do *something* with that information.

It's generally impossible to know whether a zone will ever have computations happen in it again, until the zone gets garbage collected.
Someone could have stored the zone in a global variable, to later call `storedZone.run(() { any code here });`